# Refresh div on click with smarty content

Tags: php, html, refresh, smarty

I need to refresh a div, but his content has a smarty tags... I try this, but doesn't work:

```
    <div>{Gbook action='form'}</div>

<a id="refresh"><h5>Refresh</h5></a> 

<div id="guestbook">
  <div id="interno">{Gbook}</div>
</div>

{literal}
<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#guestbook").load("#interno")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>
{/literal}
```

any help?

Comment: What about? `<a id="refresh" href="#"><h5>Refresh</h5></a>`

Comment: nothing happens... I think the problem is the smarty tag...

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery isn't connecting to php, so it cannot know the value of `$Gbook`. You will need to use Ajax if you want it to actually refresh/update.

Also, you have a syntax error:

```
<div id="interno">{$Gbook}</div>
```